# Substitute a part of string in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

What I want is :
original string : `(#1 AND #12) OR #10`
convert to : `(something AND another_something) OR something_another`

mean to say is, according to `#number` replace it by a unique string

What I did is :

```
filter_string = "(#1 AND #12) OR #10"
for fltr in filters_array:
        index = fltr[0] #numbers coming from here
        replace_by = fltr[1] #this string will replace original one
        filter_string = re.sub(r'#'+str(index),replace_by,filter_string)
```

Output :

```
(something AND something2) OR something0
```

The Problem : rather then replacing #1 it replaces #12 and #11 also because #12 also have #1.
I tried with `count = 1` in `re.sub()` function but it did not worked because my string can be '`(#12 AND #1)`' as well.

Comment: What does your `filters_array` look like?

Comment: its like [(1,"something"),(10,"something_another"),(12,"another_something")]

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'#'+str(index)+'$',replace_by_filter_string)`. The `$` matches the end of strings. [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: no but its not end-of-string it can be (#12 AND #1) as well. so after #number as colsing brace ')' and similarly a space may exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may convert the list of tuples into a dictionary and use a `re.sub` with a pattern capturing the digit part and then a lambda expression in the replacement argument to find the right value by key:

```
import re
filter_string = "(#1 AND #12) OR #10"
filters_array = [(1,"something"),(10,"something_another"),(12,"another_something")]
dt = dict(filters_array)
filter_string = re.sub(r'#([0-9]+)', lambda x: dt[int(x.group(1))] if int(x.group(1)) in dt else x.group(), filter_string)
print(filter_string)
# => (something AND another_something) OR something_another
```

The `#([0-9]+)` pattern matches `#` and then matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits. Then, inside the lambda, the numeric value is used to fetch the existing value. If it does not exist, the `#` + the number will be inserted back into the result.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4tIO7G).

If you need to further process the match, you may want to use a *callback* method rather than a lamda in the replacement argument:

```
import re

filters_array = [(1,"something"),(10,"something_another"),(12,"another_something")]
dt = dict(filters_array)

def repl(m):
    return dt[int(m.group(1))] if int(m.group(1)) in dt else m.group()

filter_string = re.sub(r'#([0-9]+)', repl, "(#1 AND #12) OR #10")
print(filter_string)
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/LtgGZw).

Comment: i tries this code,it worked. but is this approach efficient?

Comment: @RajShah: Note that with this approach, the string is only replaced *once*. When you use a loop, you modify the string as many times as there are items in your `filters_array`. Another note: the regex may be `r'#([0-9]+)\b'` depending on the requirements.

Comment: my string wil have unique numbers only.so no problem.

Comment: @RajShah If you have 100 numbers, do you want to change your string 100 times, or only once? Surely, it is up to you.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Then a callback is more appropriate than a lambda, still this approach is more efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, good for you. In your case - separate function would be better than lambda, you may adjust your approach

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew :  Got it, changing string once only will be more efficient. And I can use callback for further processing.

Comment: @RajShah: Good, I added another snippet with a callback invocation example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no need to get matched group value and casting to `int` twice. Save it in variable beforehand

Answer (score 3):

Use word boundary `\\b` anchor to force an exact number matching:

```
filter_string = "(#1 AND #12) OR #10"
filters_array = [(1,"something"),(10,"something_another"),(12,"another_somet‌​hing")]
for num,s in filters_array:
    filter_string = re.sub(r'#'+ str(num) +'\\b', s, filter_string)

print(filter_string)
```

The output:

```
(something AND another_somet‌​hing) OR something_another
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html